# Moshi: problem with platform class BigDecimal

Tags: android, json, moshi

I have a class:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class DayAveragePriceModel(
    val asset: Asset,
    val value: BigDecimal
)
```

where `Asset` is a custom class I have. I'm trying to use `Moshi` but I'm getting the following error:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform class java.math.BigDecimal (with no annotations) requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered`

How can I work around this? I tried with

```
        return Moshi.Builder()
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .add(Object::class.java)
            .build()
    }
```

but it is crashing.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As the exception says, this is a platform type, and you need to use its public API to encode and decode it.

```
object BigDecimalAdapter {
  @FromJson fun fromJson(string: String) = BigDecimal(string)

  @ToJson fun toJson(value: BigDecimal) = value.toString()
}

return Moshi.Builder()
    .add(BigDecimalAdapter)
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()
```

Comment: I am trying to follow your example to add an adapter for ULong and UByte, but I still get the error after adding their respective adapters to the builder.

Comment: Would you please look at my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67605312/how-to-write-an-explicit-moshi-jsonadapter-for-a-livedata-object

Comment: this doesn't seem to work

Comment: @user2836943 if you open a new question with a reproducible case, i'll take a look, but this code does work.

Comment: sorry, i take back, i made a mistake, its working, thanks